# Show custom message for validation

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to validate my form using hibernate validations.

This is my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Employee implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="name")
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Column(name="mobileNumber")
    @NotNull
    private Long mobileNumber;

    @Column(name="email")
    @Pattern(regexp="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"  
    + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$")
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") @Valid Employee emp,
    BindingResult result, Model model)
{
    //validator.validate(emp, result);
    this.employeeService.addEditEmployee(emp);
    return "redirect:/employees";
}
```

When I submit the form with empty values, I get a constraint violation exception, why is that?

Comment: Please share your stackTrace..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NotEmpty: Checks whether the value is not null nor empty.So when you submit the form with empty values this validation is being checked and returning false.That's why you are getting an exception.This validation can be used for collection,char sequence, map or array, they shouldn't be null and size>0 or else this gives exception.If you are using this validation,you should send non-empty values only.

```
@NotEmpty(message="Value shouldnot be empty")
private String value;
```

Then in your controller class,do a check like below

```
 @PostMapping("/addEmployee")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<AppResponse> addEmployee(@RequestBody @Valid Employee emp, Errors errors) {
    AppResponse response = new AppResponse();
    try {

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println(errors);
            List<ObjectError> list = errors.getAllErrors();
            List<String> msgList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String msg = null;
            for (ObjectError error : list) {
                msgList.add(error.getDefaultMessage());
                msg = String.join(",", msgList);
            }
            response.setStatusCode(417);
            response.setMessage(msg);
            response.setData(new ModelMap());
            return new ResponseEntity<AppResponse>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            return "redirect:/employees";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return AppResponseOther.genericProblem();
    }
}
```